# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a C++ class and I keep getting this error although I have another class written with similar syntax that compiles without a fuss.

Here is my .h:

```
#ifndef FISHPLAYER_H
#define FISHPLAYER_H

#include "Player.h"


class FishPlayer : public Player
{
public:
    float xThrust;
    float yThrust;
    static FishPlayer* getInstance();
protected:
private:
    FishPlayer();
    ~FishPlayer();
    static FishPlayer* instance;
};

#endif
```

And Here is my .cpp :

```
#include "..\include\FishPlayer.h"

FishPlayer* FishPlayer::instance=0;  // <== I Get The Error Here

FishPlayer::FishPlayer()
{
    //ctor
    xThrust = 15.0f;
    yThrust = 6.0f;
}

FishPlayer::~FishPlayer()
{
    //dtor
}


FishPlayer* FishPlayer::getInstance() { // <== I Get The Error Here
    if(!instance) {
        instance = new FishPlayer();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I've been searching for a while now and it must be something so big I don't see it.

Here is the inheritance:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include "Ennemy.h"

class Player : public Ennemy
{
    public:
    protected:
        Player();
        ~Player();
    private:
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

And the higher one:

```
#ifndef ENNEMY_H
#define ENNEMY_H

#include "Doodad.h"

class Ennemy : public Doodad
{
    public:
        float speedX;
        float maxSpeedX;
        float speedY;
        float maxSpeedY;
        float accelerationX;
        float accelerationY;
        Ennemy();
        ~Ennemy();
    protected:
    private:
};
```

And the superclass

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>


enum DoodadType{FishPlayer,Player,AstroPlayer,Ennemy,DoodadT = 999};
enum DoodadRange{Close, Medium , Far};
enum EvolutionStage{Tiny, Small, Average, Large};

class Doodad
{
    public:
        float score;
        void die();
        EvolutionStage evolutionStage;
        DoodadRange range;
        Doodad();
        virtual ~Doodad();
        Doodad(Doodad const& source);
        std::vector<Animation> animations;
        double posX;
        double posY;
        std::string name;
        std::string currentAnimation;
        int currentFrame;
        DoodadType type();
        SDL_Surface getSpriteSheet();
        bool moving;
        void update();
    protected:
    private:
        SDL_Surface spriteSheet;
};
```

Comment: I would help you, but a Singleton? That wouldn't really "help".

Comment: It compiles upon taking out the inheritance and player.h include.

Comment: Does `Player.h` include `FishPlayer.h`?

Comment: no, it does not include FishPlayer.h, I edited the post to put the rest of the code.                                                        How would a singleton not really help me?

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: I pointed them out in the second block of code with // <==

Comment: Just a hunch (I can't verify since you haven't provided an [**SSCCE**](http://sscce.org/)!), but does the error go away if you define the instance using the `class` tag, to differentiate it from the one in `DoodadType`: `class FishPlayer* FishPlayer::instance=0;`?

Comment: solved just under, I had just started to do a SSCCE, I'll start there next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you use `FishPlayer` as a enum value in `Doodad.h`

It is the same name as the class you're trying to declare. That might be the source of the problem.

Generally it's a good idea to use `FISH_PLAYER`, or `Type_FishPlayer` sort of naming scheme for enum values to avoid clashes like this.

Comment: Nice one, I had a similar error, thus the "DoodadT=999;" at the end of the enum.